# How to enable gzip compression on my web

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have tried everything copied many codes but it is not working. Here is my full `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Also tried the following code

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Despite that in inspect network tab of the browser it is still showing the following

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Connection:close
Content-Length:3482
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 08 Dec 2015 10:58:14 GMT
Expires:Thu, 07 Jan 2016 10:58:14 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17
```

I have tried opera and Firefox too but the same result. Removed cache but no effect. I have used some online checking sites which also shows site isn't gzipped.

Comment: Is the module installed? `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` and `<ifModule mod_gzip.c>` mean that you won't get an error message otherwise.

Comment: In my `phpinfo()`  there is written `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING gzip, deflate, sdch` but after deleting IfModule there is no error anywhere.

Comment: Hey, no, both [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_deflate.html) and [mod_gzip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-gzip/) are **Apache** modules, they have nothing to do with PHP!

Comment: then anyway to check them?

Comment: You said your server has *both* modules installed?

Comment: I don't have any idea about installation of modules, I just said any way to check them if they are installed.

Comment: You said "after deleting IfModule there is no error anywhere". That suggest your Apache installation recognises directives from both modules :-? Whatever, you can check installed modules in several ways: verifying the `LoadModule` directives in httpd.conf, configuring a [/server-info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_info.html) page...